# How do I take in multiple variables in a file python file read

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Lets say I have `data.txt`, and this is inside

```
0
0
0
```

How do I get the data from this in one single line? I tried something like

```
file_in = open('data.txt', 'w+')
a, b, c = file_in.read().split()
```

but it didn't work so well. How do I correctly get `a`, `b`, and `c` to each get values of `0`, from the `data.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `splitlines`:

```
file_in = open('data.txt', 'w+')
a, b, c = file_in.read().splitlines()
```

If you want to convert them to integers, try adding a `list` comprehension:

```
file_in = open('data.txt', 'w+')
a, b, c = [int(i) for i in file_in.read().splitlines()]
```

But if there are possibly not integer-like values in the text file, you could try using an `if` statement:

```
file_in = open('data.txt', 'w+')
a, b, c = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in file_in.read().splitlines()]
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! i'll accept once stack allows me to accept

Comment: @dinosauce34 My pleasure :-) Remember to upvote too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, your file opening is clearing the file. You want to open the file for reading -- use the `r` mode.

To do the unpacking, you can use the [`splitlines()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_splitlines.asp) method.

For example:

```
file_in = open('data.txt', 'r')
a, b, c = file_in.read().splitlines()
print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have numbers, and know exactly how many, and you actually want `int` objects, all you need is:

```
a, b, c = map(int, open('data.txt'))
```